# How to use column positions from one dataframe to select indices for another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df1:

```
Col1  Col2
10      100
5      90
7      87
1      83
3      70
```

I need to use Col1 indices from df1 for selecting columns from df2.

df2

```
Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4   Col5  Col6 ...................Col 20
```

So basically I need columns 10,5,7,1,3 from df2

How can I do that?

df2 expected Output:

```
Col 10    Col 5 Col 7  Col 1  Col 3
 Value1    V1    V1    V1     V1
```

where Value1, V1 are random values as present in df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with subtract `Col1` by `1`, because python count from `0`, so for select first column need `0`:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(3,12))).rename(columns= lambda x: f'col{x+1}')
print (df2)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10  col11  col12
0     0     8     3     6     3     3     7     8     0      0      8      9
1     3     7     2     3     6     5     0     4     8      6      4      1
2     1     5     9     5     6     6     6     5     4      6      4      2

#selected first column by 0 index  
print (df2.iloc[:, 0])
0    0
1    3
2    1
Name: col1, dtype: int32

#selected second column by 1 index  
print (df2.iloc[:, 1])
0    8
1    7
2    5
Name: col2, dtype: int32

df3 = df2.iloc[:, df1['Col1'] - 1]
print (df3)
   col10  col5  col7  col1  col3
0      0     3     7     0     3
1      6     6     0     3     2
2      6     6     6     1     9
```

Comment: @noob - Because python count from `0`

Comment: @noob - Are you sure?

Comment: Can you please explain what will happen if we dont use minus 1

Comment: answers are different if we use minus one and if we dont use minus one

Comment: @noob - added some sample data, I hope now it is more clear.